# code signing and notarizing existing dmg using install4j UI/command line

Tags: code-signing, install4j, notarize

I already have a dmg which is built using install4j 7.0.8. I want to code sign and notarise the dmg. I know notarisation support came in install4j 8 onwards. Is there any way I can code sign & notarise an existing dmg in install4j 9.0.4 rather than building it from scratch and then notarising it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because support for notarization affects the contents of the application bundle. You would have to generate the DMG again with the current version.